# file_get_html retrieve innertext of p but not from class

Tags: php, html

```
<div itemprop="commentText" class='post entry-content '>
  <blockquote  class="ipsBlockquote" data-author="B.A" data-cid="53143" data-time="1436336618">
    <div>
      <p>Text that I dont want</p>
    </div>
  </blockquote>
  <p>Text that I want!</p>
  <p>Text that I want!</p>
  <blockquote  class="ipsBlockquote" data-author="Mayor" data-cid="53141" data-time="1436336888">
    <div>
      <p>Text that I dont want</p>
      <p>Text that I dont want!&nbsp;</p>
      <p>Text that I dont want!&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
  </blockquote>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>Text to retrieve</p>
</div>
```

How do I go about retrieving the text in `<p>` tags that does not belong to the `<blockquote class="ipsBlockquote" ...>` tags?

```
foreach($html->find('div[itemprop=commentText]') as $element) {
   foreach($element->find('p [!ipsBlockquote]') as $element2) {
       echo $element2->innertext;
   }
}
```

This is what I have. It still retrieves the text that I don't want.